# How to calculate the exact number of legal Tic Tac Toe states for order n?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, game-theory

I want to know the exact number of legal states for Tic Tac Toe order 5 (25 cells), for each of the 25 turns. I need it to determine recursion depth of my AI.

So below are the rules of Tic Tac Toe for order n I am using:

There are n rows and n columns on a board, for a total of $n^2$ cells.

All cells are initially empty.

There are two players, each player take turns alternatively, no player can move in two consecutive turns.

Game ends when one player has filled n cells of the same row, column or diagonal. Or the whole board is filled.

So without any consideration of the rules above, each cell can be in 3 states, naively the absolute upper bound of number of states for order n is $3^{n^2}$, for orders 3, 4, 5 they are 19,683, 43,046,721 and 847,288,609,443 respectively. Of course, most of them are illegal and cannot be reached via normal gameplay.

I have programmatically checked all Tic Tac Toe states for order 3 and 4.

```
from typing import List, Tuple


def pack(line: range, last: int) -> int:
    return (sum(1 << last - i for i in line), tuple(line))


def generate_lines(n: int) -> List[Tuple[int, Tuple[int]]]:
    square = n * n
    last = square - 1
    lines = []
    for i in range(n):
        lines.extend(
            (
                pack(range(i * n, i * n + n), last),
                pack(range(i, square, n), last),
            )
        )

    lines.extend(
        (
            pack(range(0, square, n + 1), last),
            pack(range((m := n - 1), n * m + 1, m), last),
        )
    )
    return lines


LINES = [generate_lines(i) for i in (3, 4, 5)]


def check_state_3(board: Tuple[int, int, int]) -> Tuple[bool, int]:
    for line, _ in LINES[0]:
        for i in (0, 1):
            if board[i] & line == line:
                return True, i

    return board[2].bit_count() == 9, None


GAMESTATES_3_P1 = set()
GAMESTATES_3_P2 = set()
POSITIONS = [[1 << i for i in line[::-1]] for line in [range(9), range(16), range(25)]]


def tally_states_3(board: Tuple[int, int, int], move: bool, states: set) -> None:
    if board not in states:
        if not check_state_3(board)[0]:
            o, x, full = board
            for i in POSITIONS[0]:
                if not full & i:
                    if move:
                        tally_states_3((o, x | i, full | i), 0, states)
                    else:
                        tally_states_3((o | i, x, full | i), 1, states)

        states.add(board)


tally_states_3((0, 0, 0), 0, GAMESTATES_3_P1)
tally_states_3((0, 0, 0), 1, GAMESTATES_3_P2)


def check_state_4(board: Tuple[int, int, int]) -> Tuple[bool, int]:
    for line, _ in LINES[1]:
        for i in (0, 1):
            if board[i] & line == line:
                return True, i

    return board[2].bit_count() == 16, None


def tally_states_4(board: Tuple[int, int, int], move: bool, states: set) -> None:
    if board not in states:
        if not check_state_4(board)[0]:
            o, x, full = board
            for i in POSITIONS[1]:
                if not full & i:
                    if move:
                        tally_states_4((o, x | i, full | i), 0, states)
                    else:
                        tally_states_4((o | i, x, full | i), 1, states)

        states.add(board)

GAMESTATES_4_P1 = set()
GAMESTATES_4_P2 = set()

tally_states_4((0, 0, 0), 0, GAMESTATES_4_P1)
tally_states_4((0, 0, 0), 1, GAMESTATES_4_P2)

print(len(GAMESTATES_3_P1))
print(len(GAMESTATES_3_P2))
print(len(GAMESTATES_3_P1 | GAMESTATES_3_P2))
print(len(GAMESTATES_4_P1))
print(len(GAMESTATES_4_P2))
print(len(GAMESTATES_4_P1 | GAMESTATES_4_P2))
```

```
5478
5478
8533
9722011
9722011
14782023
```

So for Tic Tac Toe order 3, there are 5478 legal states reachable if player X moves first, this counts all reflections and rotations as distinct boards. There are also 5478 states reachable if player O moves first. For a total of 8533 unique states.
I have reached the same counts using various methods and I have verified the correctness of the results thoroughly.

It took quite some time and Gibibytes of RAM to crunch the numbers for order 4. So 9722011 states are reachable if either player moves first, and 14782023 states in total.

My result is the same as what I got from this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/613505/1061426).

```
      N:   1   2     3        4
 -------   -  --  ----  -------
 ply  0:   1   1     1        1
 ply  1:   1   4     9       16
 ply  2:   -  12    72      240
 ply  3:   -  12   252     1680 
 ply  4:   -   0   756    10920
 ply  5:   -   -  1260    43680
 ply  6:   -   -  1520   160160 
 ply  7:   -   -  1140   400400
 ply  8:   -   -   390   895950
 ply  9:   -   -    78  1433520
 ply 10:   -   -     -  1962576
 ply 11:   -   -     -  1962576          
 ply 12:   -   -     -  1543080
 ply 13:   -   -     -   881760
 ply 14:   -   -     -   333792
 ply 15:   -   -     -    83440
 ply 16:   -   -     -     8220 
 =======   =  ==  ====  =======  
  TOTAL:   2  29  5478  9722011
 -------
```

Obviously I cannot use the same method to enumerate all the valid states for order 5.

According to the answer:

- There are ${{N^2} \choose x}$ ways to place $x$ `X` marks on an $N\times{}N$ board.
- There are ${{N^2 - x} \choose o}$ ways to place $o$ `O` marks on an $N\times{}N$ board that is already filled with $x$ `X`s.

Hence *ignoring winners* there are:

${{N^2} \choose x} \times {{N^2 - x} \choose o}$

distinct boards at ply $p$. Or (plugging the definitions of $x$ and $o$ from above):

${{N^2} \choose {floor({{p+1}\over{2}})}} \times {{N^2 - {floor({{p+1}\over{2}})}} \choose {floor({p \over 2})}}$

So I have tried to calculate the number using the formula:

```
from typing import List


class Pascal_Triangle:
    def __init__(self, end_row: int = 3):
        self.data = [[1], [1, 1], [1, 2, 1]]
        self.length = 3
        if end_row > 3:
            self.add_rows(end_row)

    def add_rows(self, end_row: int):
        last_row = self.data[-1]
        for n in range(self.length, end_row):
            mid = n // 2 + 1
            row = [a + b for a, b in zip(last_row, last_row[1:mid])]
            self.data.append(last_row := [1] + row + row[mid - 3 + n % 2 :: -1] + [1])

        self.length = end_row

    def pretty_print(self):
        longest = len(str(self.data[-1][self.length // 2]))
        line_length = (longest + 1) * (self.length - 1) + longest
        for row in self.data:
            print(" ".join(f"{n:^{longest}}" for n in row).center(line_length))
            print()

    def choose(self, r: int, c: int) -> int:
        if r + 1 > self.length:
            self.add_rows(r + 1)

        return self.data[r][c]


PT = Pascal_Triangle(26)


def count_boards(n: int) -> List[int]:
    square = n * n
    boards = []
    counts = [0, 0]
    for i in range(square + 1):
        a, b = counts
        boards.append(PT.choose(square, a) * PT.choose(square - a, b))
        counts[i % 2] += 1

    return boards
```

I got the following results:

```
In [78]: print(count_boards(3))
[1, 9, 72, 252, 756, 1260, 1680, 1260, 630, 126]

In [79]: print(count_boards(4))
[1, 16, 240, 1680, 10920, 43680, 160160, 400400, 900900, 1441440, 2018016, 2018016, 1681680, 960960, 411840, 102960, 12870]

In [80]: print(count_boards(5))
[1, 25, 600, 6900, 75900, 531300, 3542000, 16824500, 75710250, 257414850, 823727520, 2059318800, 4805077200, 8923714800, 15297796800, 21034470600, 26293088250, 26293088250, 23371634000, 16360143800, 9816086280, 4461857400, 1622493600, 405623400, 67603900, 5200300]

In [81]: print(sum(count_boards(3)))
6046

In [82]: print(sum(count_boards(4)))
10165779

In [83]: print(sum(count_boards(5)))
161995031226
```

It is clear the numbers are not exact, since it is clearly stated that the counts disregard winners. These counts include states that can only be reached when the game didn't end when there is a winner, which is illegal. More specifically, the numbers are larger from turn 2n onward.

Is there a way to calculate the exact value of number of valid Tic Tac Toe boards for order n?